# force delete freeware that works on windows 7

Tags: windows-7, windows

There was a freeware unlocker that did work on xp, on win 7 doesn't seem to show up in explorer context menu so any other ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try [this registry](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/add-take-ownership-to-explorer-right-click-menu-in-vista/) entry to add "Take Ownership" to the conext menu

[image: take ownership]

After taking ownership you may be able to delete the file.

Comment: This should really be a comment...

Comment: @Hello71 I disagree. The OP is looking for a way to "force delete" files. Although he asked for software, RJFalconer is trying to solve the OP's problem rather than trying to answer the question as asked.

Comment: That's a good answer for me.

Comment: I stand corrected.